# How to get this abstract blurry effect on my picture?

Tags: reverse-engineering, effect

I really like the blurry effect on the tunnel walls and ceiling in [this photograph by Joko on 500px](http://500px.com/photo/28451813). I get disappointed with my pictures when I see something like that. Can someone explain me how he did that? Is this kind of Photoshop effect, or some kind of technique?

Comment: Can you describe the image in words, and particularly the aspect you are interested in?

Comment: Picture is taken by Nikon, that's why I used Nikon tag.

Comment: What I like in the picture is this blurry effect on right and left side of the picture. Also, this effect on ceiling is so modern and abstract. What kind of effect did he used?

Comment: Ok, thnx, I will try to change it ;)

Comment: I'm not saying all this to attack you or the question, by the way. Editing it to include this info will both get better answers for you (I would have focused on the silhouette rather than the blur of the tunnel), and also increases the chance that someone with the _same_ interest will ever find the question later. Right now, even if this gets a great answer, someone else might wonder the exact some title ("How to get this type of picture?") but be wondering about a crisp and colorful flower photograph.

Comment: No, your comments are very helpful and true, and you are right I didn't think when I put my question. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the photographer used the zoom effect. It consists in zooming in (or out, but mostly in) while you are taking the picture. Not before, not after, but while you are taking the picture. You can read more about this particular effect [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/using-the-zoom-effect).

It's pretty difficult to achieve, and takes a lot of practice. You'd want to use a tripod and long exposure time, as well as a small aperture to have a higher depth of field with your subject in focus.

Comment: I think this is it. Well done! I totally forgot on my zoom! Well done!

Comment: maybe he did this for one exposure and another sharp fast exposure and overlayed them?

Comment: why do that when you can just fire the flash, as per my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a combination of zooming during a long exposure, with flash so that there is a sharp exposure of the figure.